# Multiple power supplies for a high-current electronics project

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, circuit-design, high-current, prototyping

I'm doing a project combining different electronic modules with an Arduino Uno. There are five semi-independent pre-assembled modules that I need to power, and with whom the Arduino interacts with (detecting if some inputs are on or off by tension - by "hijacking" some LED power sources, and cutting the module's power supply via a transistor).

A single module works fine while powered by an Arduino for prototyping, but I need to find a solution with sufficient current for the five modules. The modules and currents are:

- 4 HDMI switches (drawing around **~150mA** each)
- USB switch (**2A** max)
- Arduino Uno (sources say 500mA to 2A, but I'm counting on **1A** to be stable enough)

---

**First approach**

In total I'd need around 3.6A 5VDC, maybe 4, to power everything. My first approach was to look at supplying power via a voltage regulator (I have a 12VDC 5A power brick that I want to use) to convert it to 5VDC, but common voltage regulators stop at around 1/1.5A, and I know putting some regulators in parallel is a bad idea.

I've seen solutions [like this one](https://www.electroschematics.com/lm7805-voltage-regulator/) using an LM7805, so would something like this be a good approach, provided it could reach 4 or 5A?

---

**Other (and maybe favourite right now) approach**

However, I have some concerns about concentrating that much current in a PCB surface, so I though of an alternative approach, where each module would have its own voltage regulator supplying power to it. This would result in 6 "power supplies" *, each with its own voltage regulator, albeit all drawing power from the same power brick.

My concern here is whether that could lead to some "interference", given that the Arduino will have to measure tension in the modules, and that measured voltage will not be supplied by the same regulator as the Arduino's. Moreover, the Arduino will also control a transistor that cuts the module's power supply (though I could use some kind of relay or MOSFET for isolation in the later case).

So the big question is whether 6 "isolated" modules, each with its own regulator, can "interact" (for lack of a better term) with each other, namely for controlling transistors or sensing eachother's tensions, and if they share the same ground, given that the DC current comes from the same brick.

Thanks for your attention!

---

*: The four HDMI modules could use the same supply, bringing the total to 3 supplies, but I digress.

Comment: FWIW, the Uno will use much less than 500mA. Probably closer to 50.

Comment: You want 5V power, right? And you want the input to be 12V?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention 5V power in the circuit, down from 12V

Comment: Presumably your measurements imply a common ground (if not you have *many* other challenges!) so you *could* use distinct regulators.  But linear regulators are wasteful; really you should find a good 4 amp 5 volt switching mains supply to have some margin.  Trying to regulate down the existing supply is *possible* but adds a lot of complexity and potential failure.

Comment: "detecting if some inputs are on or off by tension" do you mean by the *voltage* on a pin somewhere?

Comment: Tension seems to be the root word for voltage in some language/traditions; in contemporary English it's not "wrong" as much as "unusual"

Comment: I know, I wanted to be sure.  In fact, if it's an overhead power line we say "is that high tension?" and we don't mean is the wire getting pulled on hard.

Comment: Are you going to be communicating with these modules using digital signals exclusively?  Or will you be reading analog voltages?

Comment: If you can't find a regulator that does what you want (5V 4A is not that bad, you should be able to find a buck converter module) then it's time to get into building your own buck converter with an off-the-shelf control chip.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Indeed I might end up buying a 5V brick if this adds too much complexity to the project, just wanted to be sure

Comment: @TimWescott I'll use the Arduino analog pins to measure voltage, so analog too; plus I was thinking of controlling a transistor via the Arduino to cut off the module's power supply when needed

Comment: Beware you typically must not have any I/O signals running to an unpowered device; unless otherwise specified I/O voltages must not exceed the range of a device's current power supply by more than a diode drop.

Comment: Let me clarify: do you need to know the voltage, or just that it's comfortably above some threshold?  I can give you a preview of my answer though -- having a bunch of 12-5V converters is probably OK.  A 7805 would dissipate a huge amount of power (12V to 5V with a linear converter is automatically less than 5/12 efficient -- 41% efficiency is pretty poor compared to the 85 to 95% you can expect from a switcher).

Comment: @TimWescott Just an approximated value; the efficiency is a good point though

Comment: @ChrisStratton Would it be ok if I'm just measuring a value as an input? Nonetheless, I don't intend to do any reading if the module's state is off. Should I pull the connection to ground or something like that to be sure?

Comment: If the measuring device (Arduino?) is powered and not biasing the input signal with additional circuitry then yes, it could measure something that is powered off.  But if the thing being measured were powered and the Arduino was not, you'd have a problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Right, the Arduino will always be on, and the modules are the ones that can be off, so it seems ok... But thanks for the heads up!

Comment: If the loads are split, you could use multiple 12V-5V adapters, yes? There’s no need for the rails to be tied together from the way you describe it. In that case, multiple 12V-5V point-of-load modules could do this.

Comment: @hacktastical There's intercommunication between modules so my doubt was precisely about whether having more than 1 POL was ok, but it seems so.